# limits of multiple functions using epsilon delta proof

Tags: limits

Hi there how would you prove something like this using the epsilon delta proof. Let $a∈\Bbb{R}$ Assume that $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x)=l$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to a} g(x) = m$ if $c$ and $d$ are real numbers then $$\lim \limits_{x \to a}cf(x) + dg(x) = cl + dm.$$

Comment: Proving the linearity property is not too bad - arrange things correctly in the epsilon-inequality and use the triangle inequality.

Comment: read all the answers .

Answer (score 0):

For any positive real number $\epsilon$, since limx→a f(x)=l and limx→a g(x) = m, there are positive $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ such that $|f(a+\delta_1^-)-l|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2c}$ and $|g(a+\delta_2^-)-m|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2d}$ for any positive $\delta_1^-\leq\delta_1$ and $\delta_2^-\leq\delta_2$.

Let $\delta = min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$, then $|cf(a+\delta^-)-cl+dg(a+\delta^-)-dm|\leq \epsilon$ for all positive $\delta^-\leq\delta$. Hence limx→a(cf(x) + dg(x)) = cl + dm.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we assume $cd\neq0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ given.

$$lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l \implies $$

$\exists \delta_1 >0 :$

$( |x-a|<\delta_1$ 
$\implies |f(x)-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{2|c|}).$

and by the same

$\exists \delta_2>0 : $

$(|x-a|<\delta_2$
$\implies |g(x)-m|<\frac{\epsilon}{2|d|}).$

take now

$\color{blue}{\delta=min(\delta_1,\delta_2)}$

so

$|x-a|<\delta \implies$

$|x-a|<\delta_2 \;$ and $\;|x-a|<\delta_2|$
$\implies$

$|c(f(x)-l)+d(g(x)-m)|\leq$

$|c||f(x)-l|+|d||g(x)-m)|<\frac{\epsilon}
{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Qed.

Answer (score 0):

1) Prove that $\lim_{x \to a} cf(x)=cl$
If $c=0$ then $cf(x)=0$ and the the result is trivial
Suppose $c \neq 0$ and let $\varepsilon >0$ be given
Consider $\varepsilon' = \frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}$
By definition of $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=l$, we have: $\exists \delta>0, \forall x \in ]a-\delta, a+\delta[, |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon'$
That is $|c||f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$ and finally $|cf(x)-cl|<\varepsilon$
Therefore $\lim_{x \to a} cf(x)=cl$

2) Prove that  $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)+g(x)=l+m$
Consider $\varepsilon' = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$
By definition of $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=l$, we have: $\exists \delta_1>0, \forall x \in ]a-\delta_1, a+\delta_1[, |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon'$
By definition of $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)=m$, we have: $\exists \delta_2>0, \forall x \in ]a-\delta_2, a+\delta_2[, |g(x)-m|<\varepsilon'$
Let $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$
Then $\forall x \in ]a-\delta, a+\delta[, |f(x)-l|+|g(x)-m|<2\varepsilon'=\varepsilon$
And since $|(f(x)-l)+(g(x)-m)| \leq |f(x)-l|+|g(x)-m|$
We get $|(f(x)+g(x))-(l+m)|<\varepsilon$
That is $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)+g(x)=l+m$

If you combine the 2 arguments you have your result